# Facebook Graph API does not return the posts on my wall which i shared from some random user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, shared, posts

I have shared a post from a random user and it shows in my Facebook wall with the message i have provided but Graph API is not retrieving it when i query using me/posts. Is it possible to retrieve such posts on my wall through GRAPH API. I am using an access token with all available permissions. So permissions should not be an issue. Could someone let me know if there is a way to get such posts.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Why would you need those posts?

Comment: The client wants it. I am not sure how this would be relevant to deducing the answer to the question. Anyways!

Comment: Because what you are doing may not be allowed by Facebook Platform Policy. So I rather not help you get your app banned forever